# comparing two files and reordering columns in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two files. One file has some IDs and the other has pair of IDs.

So file1 looks like:

```
abc3756968
abc9483504
```

and file2 looks like:

```
abc6917833  abc3756968  0.817637
abc6920271  abc3756968  0.984551
abc4275081  abc3756968  0.834717
abc2209154  **abc3756968**  0.8642
abc10457594 **abc3756968**  0.763052
**abc3756968**  abc9493450  1
**abc3756968**  abc9483504  1
abc3756968  abc9389034  0.775731
abc3756968  abc2236381  0.775731
abc3756968  abc2236382  0.775731
abc3756968  abc9399043  0.994849
abc3756968  abc9321374  0.764408
abc3756968  abc9399044  0.775731
abc3756968  abc7452703  1
abc3756968  abc4599669  0.775731
abc6917833  abc9483504  0.817637
abc6920271  abc9483504  0.984551
abc4275081  abc9483504  0.834717
abc2209154  abc9483504  0.8642
abc10457594 abc9483504  0.763052
abc3756968  abc9483504  1
abc9493450  abc9483504  1
abc9483504  abc9389034  0.775731
abc9483504  abc2236381  0.775731
abc9483504  abc2236382  0.775731
abc9483504  abc9399043  0.994849
abc9483504  abc9321374  0.764408
abc9483504  abc9399044  0.775731
abc9483504  abc7452703  1
```

Now I would like to re order my file such that the ids in file1 `abc9483504` will be reordered to be in single column. Before they were either in column1 or column2 like

```
abc3756968  abc6917833  0.817637
abc3756968  abc6920271  0.984551
abc3756968  abc4275081  0.834717
abc3756968  abc2209154  0.8642
abc3756968  abc10457594 0.763052
abc3756968  abc9493450  1
abc3756968  abc9483504  1
abc3756968  abc9389034  0.775731
abc3756968  abc2236381  0.775731
abc3756968  abc2236382  0.775731
abc3756968  abc9399043  0.994849
abc3756968  abc9321374  0.764408
abc3756968  abc9399044  0.775731
abc3756968  abc7452703  1
abc3756968  abc4599669  0.775731
abc3756968  abc9483504  1
abc9483504  abc3756968  1
abc9483504  abc6917833  0.817637
abc9483504  abc6920271  0.984551
abc9483504  abc4275081  0.834717
abc9483504  abc2209154  0.8642
abc9483504  abc10457594 0.763052
abc9483504  abc3756968  1
abc9483504  abc9493450  1
abc9483504  abc9389034  0.775731
abc9483504  abc2236381  0.775731
abc9483504  abc2236382  0.775731
abc9483504  abc9399043  0.994849
abc9483504  abc9321374  0.764408
abc9483504  abc9399044  0.775731
abc9483504  abc7452703  1
```

I have written a program but I know it takes a lot of time to search each ID and reorder if I have say 100000 IDs to search for. My program is

```
rs_dict={}
with open("file1") as rs:
    for line in rs:
        rs_dict[line.strip()]=1 


for rs in rs_dict.keys():
    with open("file2") as ld:
        for line in ld:
            if rs in line.strip().split():
                if rs==line.strip().split()[0]:
                    print line.strip()
                else:
                    print line.strip().split()[1]+"\t"+line.strip().split()[0]+"\t"+line.strip().split()[2]
```

I would like to know a smarter way of doing it like using pandas etc. I am a biologist wants to become a decent programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is slow because it loops entirely through `file2` for each ID in `file1` which is `O(n*m)`.

Instead, you should loop once through `file2` and store data at the same time, then iterate through `file1` and displays corresponding elements, which is `O(n+m)`.

Note that you can also use `defaultdict` and EAFP to avoid having to check if key is already present in the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open("file2") as f2:
    for line in f2:
        id1, id2, val = line.strip().split()
        data[id1].append((id2, val))
        data[id2].append((id1, val))

with open("file1") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        id = line.strip()
        try:
            for a, b in data[id]:
                print("%s %s %s" % (id, a, b))
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop you are opening and reading file2 as many times as there are keys in file1. The slowness is probably related to the underlying operating system (not) cacheing the contents of file2.

How large is file2? If less than what can reasonably be stored in RAM on your computer (typically a few hundred MB) then try cacheing it yourself:

```
f = open("file2", "r")
cache = []
for line in f: cache.append(line )
# you now have cache, a list of lines from file2
```

and then remove the `with` from your second block and replace the second `for` by `for line in cache`

This is still seriously sub-optimal. It's better still to build a python dict from the contents of file2 so that you can then access only the lines that you want rather than scanning all of them. Something like

```
cache = {}
f = open("file2", "r")
for line in f:
    t = line.strip().split()
    key1 = t[0]
    if not key1 in cache: cache[key1] = []
    cache[key1].append(line)
    key2 = t[1]
    if not key2 in cache: cache[key2] = []
    cache[key2].append(line)
```

almost-repeated code for simplicity of comprehension. More generally you'd run an inner loop over the words in the line that split() generates.

now the second block of code becomes far simpler. Outline:

```
for rs in rs_dict.keys():
    if rs in cache:
       cached_lines = cache[rs]
       # cached_lines is a list of one or more lines containing rs
       # as the first or second word
    else
       # rs wasn't in file2 at all
```

As well as simpler it will be much faster, because a Python dict uses data strictures that locate entities by key much faster than can be achieved by checking every item of a list.

For completeness, if file1 and file2 are both enormous (Gigabytes upwards), you should load their contents into a database such as sqlite. A database does on disk what a dict does in RAM: makes access to selected elements by key far more efficient than a simple search through all the records.